# All IOutlet properties are "nil" in a view controller when running test on iOS 11 Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios11

I'm getting an issue in iOS 11 Simulator where in a certain unit test, all the IBOutlet properties of a swift view controller are "nil", and where the same properties were populated in iOS 10.3 and the test was also passing.

It has the additional complication that the test passes when it is run in isolation, and **also passes on the the device**. It only fails on the iOS 11 simulator, **and when run with all the other tests**.

Comment: MCVE is not necessarily possible at this time. As mentioned in the description, when the test is run in isolation, it passes. So that leaves the entire rest of the app and its interactions with UIKit as source of the bug. I'll need more ideas about how to track this down.

Comment: Trying to make the MCVE is part of how you'll track it down. Indeed, as you say, "the rest of the app and its interactions" is part of the problem. But you didn't tell us about any of that. You have the project; we don't. You'll just have to debug, yourself. Duplicate your project and start subtracting things until the issue goes away. When it does, that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no explanation as to why the test fails on simulator + iOS 11 and not other configurations, but the issue was fixed by using a static method to create the second view controller. For some reason, the empty initializer ("CardViewController()") worked previously, but now requires the full create method like above.

I was a little mistaken about how the viewController was loaded (it is loaded in the setup() method), but I also found this resource useful:

https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-testing-view-controllers-swift/

It did not solve the issue, but is a useful reminder of possible race conditions in XCTest.